# Magento throwing 404 error in every page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I have googled and tried every solution found but with no luck. Has anyone got this problem. 
My Magento home page works just fine but as i navigate to any other pages it throws 404 error.

The rewrite module is loaded and `.htaccess` lso looks fine but the navigation is not working.

when i put index.php in the middle of domain name and the page name the url works fine!!

Comment: 4004...  what is that? it should be 404

Comment: sorry for that but you understood right??

Comment: check url category url and menu

Comment: make rewrite url reindex.

Comment: how do i do that???Did you mean system->index management->reindex?? I have already done that.But with no luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento administration issue and belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

You have misconfiguration in you system > configuration > web, you should have "use web server rewrites" set to "yes".

If it is not that, you should put more information about your problem and configuration (eg : engine, php version...)

Comment: It does not have that option called 'use server redirection url' instead 'Use Secure URLs in Frontend' and 'use web server rewrites'

Comment: use web server rewrites, I translate from French :) I edited my answer.